# How to keep docker login credentials securely on the device

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

I have docker installed on the machine.
I have written a script to pull the images from docker hub.
I manually logging into dockerhub with username and password through Script but here anyone can see the credential.
How can I keep docker login credentials securely on the device and how can I encrypt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your credentials on external services like the OS keychain. You can find a list of possibilities [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) and in this git [repo](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) and store your cred based on your demands.